# Azure pipeline- VsTest - testAssemblies does not captures TestMethod log

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

Is there anyway where we can capture test method's logs
For example: - I wrote a test method which compares the same data type lists from database A and database B.
And then , `Assert.AreEqual(listA.count, listB.count)`

List has thousands of records and take while to run.. let say it takes 1 minute time to run the test method..
and `VsTest-testAssemblies` does not capture log of that 1 minute.. Is there anyway we can record those logs.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Thanks @HughLin-MSFT, and sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What log do you want to capture? If it refers to the process of the test method, I am afraid this is impossible to achieve. The "Assert.AreEqual" method is a built-in method of VsTest. If you want to output some specific logs, you can try to write a custom test method .
If it refer to list the records of the database, you can `echo` these records in script.

`it takes 1 minute time to run the test method`  I think this one minute is used to execute the test method, during this period there could be no log generated. This is an expected behavior. If I have any misunderstandings, please point out.